# Narrowing conversion on a (int64_t * static_cast<float>(double))

Tags: c++, narrowing

I'm fixing some lint errors in a codebase I am working with, and I see the following line

```
// note offset is int64_t, scale is int64_t, x is double
int64_t y = offset + lrintf(scale * static_cast<float>(x))
```

the linter complains and says
`narrowing conversion from 'int64_t' (aka 'long') to 'float'`.

It seems the `scale * static_cast<float>(x)` is what's causing issues, and I'm wondering what is the best way to handle this error? should I cast `scale` to a double, and then call `lrintd` instead? Or is there a better approach for this case?

Comment: Why is there a cast to `float` in the first place? It only makes the result more imprecise if `x` was originally a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The `static_cast` discards some bits from the mantissa and exponent. This also limits the number of bits in the mantissa of `float(scale)`.

Note that a typical IEEE754 `double` also has insufficient bits in the mantissa to fully express every `int64_t` value. That's logical: both are 8 byte types. But float is only 4 bytes in IEEE754.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more logical to use

```
int64_t y = offset + llrint(scale * x);
```

`scale * x` will be `double` and should be rounded to `long long` (AKA `int64_t`).

Note anyway that this might modify the program behavior in some cases (truncating the `double` to `float` or not could result in different `y`).